# Maven Generate Archtype From Existing Project

Tags: java, maven

I'm attempting to generate a Maven archetype from an existing project.  I'm using the maven-archetype-plugin 2.0.  When Maven marks up my existing Java class files, it sets the package name to something similar:

```
package ${package}.${artifactId}.dao;
```

Instead, I want it to be

```
package ${package}.dao;
```

When the user creates a project based on the archetype, they typical specify groupId, artifactId, which then auto-fills the package name (using Eclipse).

```
groupId: com.mycompany
artifactId: aproject
[package: com.mycompany.aproject]
```

That leads to the double artifact name: com.mycompany.aproject.aproject.

I notice in the standard Maven archetypes, their Java source files are simply decorated with:
package ${package}

Is there some setting that I'm missing to accomplish this?

Comment: After trying multiple command line arguments to the maven-archetype-plugin, I found nothing that worked.  So, I ended up doing a mass search/replace from ${package}.${artifactId} to ${package}.  One swoop caught them all.  Not optimal, but not difficult either.

Comment: You can answer your own question with your solution and mark it as correct. That way, the question is no longer marked as unanswered.